# Including high numbers of global/constants variables

Tags: php, global-variables, constants

I'm just wondering if it's optimal to require high numbers of global variables on every single page within PHP application. Let's say a number of 1000 global variables. Is it an optimal way?

The reason I want to use global variables is to store all user notification from it's account functions in one file. But is it an optimal way? Maybe it's better to let the notification stay within class methods instead of file with global variables?

If it's non optimal, what about storing the data within constants?

Comment: why would there be that many globals? Globals pretty much should always be avoided

Comment: as I mentioned before - this file will contains all result notification data from class methods.

Comment: You *should* keep the number of globals to an absolute minimum, ideally none... however, *"... store all user notification from it's account functions in one file"* just sets alarm bells ringing, it sounds like you're approaching the problem in completely the wrong way to start with.

Comment: Good to hear that. Well I didnt start to coding this way yet. Just wondering if it's a proper way or not. If so, i will keep my globals to minimum.

Comment: @CD001 what about constants then?

Comment: The optimal number of globals in your code should be 0.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do... it sounds more like a job for a database... probably.

Comment: @CD001 user login/register/cms app and I was thinking of storing the results of all methods (for example: invalid login/invalid password etc) within globals/constants in a separate file

Comment: *"storing the results of all methods"* ... by that do you mean the messaging system? *"Invalid login"*, *"Reset password"* those kind of strings?

Comment: @CD001 exactly, sorry for my bad english

Comment: You probably want a messaging system then, with the messages themselves stored in the database, an XML file or even a CSV - don't clutter up the global variable scope ;)